# What is the best solution to check if dataset has been changed (added / edited ,deleted records)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project where the user has to be able to add or edit hours that he will work or worked. The dataset I'm using for this I retreive from ASP.net / MVC 4. What is the best way to check if the user added new data to the table or edited some data?

Example: The user loads the page, the calender is set to the current date --> table shows 3 weeks. Previous week, this week and next week. The dataset load in the hours that were retreived from ASP.net. The user adds new hours and edits some hours. Then the user clicks on the button to go to the next week. The data entered by the user has to be compared with the retreived dataset. The dataset has to be saved, this will happen in ASP.net. But after the save the browser gets the data of the next week and the calendar has to be for the next week.

The data added / edited by the user has to be saved but I have to know if this is edited or added. What is the best way to do this?

The retreived dataset = a string? Could I compare this by just comparing 2 strings? remove enters, spaces, ...

Is there a library to compare datasets in jquery?

To show the next week I think the page cannot be refreshed? Correct?

Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure on what you're going at here, however a suggestion might be to either have a save button on each page or hook up a event for whenever the input looses focus (or whatever you're using for selecting hours etc).

For the latter suggestion it would require more javascript, for example each input that's rendered could have data attributes of which year, month, and day it represents so it can be used when posting a change.

If you however prefer to submit the whole "dataset", you should checkout modelbinding if you're not already fimiliar with it, then either post the collection when clicking save or changing page.

[Scott Hanselmans article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) on how the default modelbinder works might be of any help.